# CKEditor 3.6.3 Enable browser spellcheck and disable context menu

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, contextmenu, spell-checking

I'm trying to get a spellcheck into a very bare bones implementation of `CKEditor`. I've disabled ALL the toolbars and plugins, so we're just left with a simple text box that creates basic HTML.

Is it possible re-enable the browser/OS spellchecking?

The `CKEditor` contextual menu is also pretty useless. I wouldn't mind getting rid of that too if that's possible.

Comment: Is this answer still working for you?  Because it doesn't seem to work for me, at least with google chrome...

Comment: Scratch that, it was a bug with an older version, the latest is working again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a config setting that disables the built-in spell checker if a browser provides one. It's set to true by default, try setting it to false.

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

---

You can try disabling the contextmenu plugin:

```
config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';
```