# Disable ckeditor context menu in version 4.4.6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in a Rails4 project. I have tried both the ckeditor gem and the ckeditor_rails gem to provide the ckeditor libraries.

There are multiple posts here by people wanting to remove the ckeditor context menu so that the native browser context menu can be displayed.

This is usually to enable the browser spellchecker to be used rather than the ckeditor paid / advertised spellchecker.

[how-to-remove-contextmenu-in-ckeditor-4-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023478/how-to-remove-contextmenu-in-ckeditor-4-3)

[ckeditor-3-6-3-enable-browser-spellcheck-and-disable-context-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549038/ckeditor-3-6-3-enable-browser-spellcheck-and-disable-context-menu)

[how-to-disable-ckeditor-context-menu/20229730#20229730](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246631/how-to-disable-ckeditor-context-menu/20229730#20229730)

The third link has the most replies but none of them are universally accepted.
Generally the reply is to remove the contextmenu plugin by placing the following in the ckeditor config.js

```
config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';
```

There is also the suggestion that contextmenu is a dependency on other plugins and different people add a multitude of other plugins to be removed as well.

One helpful post suggests running the following code in the console to establish the dependencies.

```
$.each(CKEDITOR.plugins, function(k, v){ 
    v.requires && console.log("Plugin '" + k + "' requires: " + v.requires) 
})
```

This seems to work well and suggests that tabletools and liststyle plugin is dependent on contextmenu. So we end up with

```
config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,tabletools,contextmenu';
```

Unfortunately this does not disable the context menu in the version of ckeditor that I am using (4.4.6 established by adding alert(CKEDITOR.version) in the config.js)

Finally there is a suggestion to use the following code in config.js

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
   ev.editor.editable().addClass('cke_enable_context_menu')
});
```

There is no suggestion as to how this is meant to disable the context menu but in any case it makes no difference for me.

For me this is a showstopper as the ckeditor context menu hides the browser spelling suggestions and the cut and paste options it contains do not actually work but just bring up the browser dialog.

> Your browser security settings don't permit the editor to
>   automatically execute copying operations. Please use the keyboard for
>   that (Ctrl/Cmd+C).

In all other aspects ckeditor does seem to be the best functioning editor out there.

Comment: config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu,tabletools'; works for me in 4.4.7.

Answer (score 4):

In my Drupal 7 environment, loading ckeditor from the CDN, current version is 4.11.4.
The only thing that worked for me after many failed alternatives:

```
config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,tableselection,tabletools,tableresize,contextmenu';
```

For convenience, I put this in the module configuration settings -> Advanced -> Custom JavaScript configuration, but in my experience the same result can be achieved in the ckeditor.config.js file in the module folder. 
(It's just more likely to get accidentally overwritten there, when updating the module. ... you could also do it by checking the option to use the config.js file in your theme and then adding the line above to that file.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the only option worked for me

Answer (score 1):

[As simple as that](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/pkkcp27x/):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
    removePlugins: 'contextmenu,tabletools' 
} );
```

If it does not help you, you must include a valid sample to reproduce the issue because something exotic is going on in your setup.

Comment: How does this differ from "confg.removePlugins etc"? I assume that in your example code the string 'textarea' refers to the id of the textarea? When I try this code (in my document.ready) I get "Uncaught The editor instance "contact_case_notes" is already attached to the provided element."

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking on how to disable the context menu and have access to the native browser spellchecker in CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    removePlugins: 'contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools,tableselection',
    disableNativeSpellChecker: false
} );
```

(tested on CKEditor 4.7.0, standard package)

Answer (score 0):

Answer for 2023 in CKEditor 4.14.0.

I was trying to disable the context menu for the usual reason. I wanted to enable the browser's native spell checker instead of the built-in pay-per-click advertising spell checker.

I had to disable all of the following:

```
config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,tableselection,tabletools,contextmenu';
```

You can pay attention to the console tab in Chrome's developer tools. CKEditor will produce dependency errors in this tab if you have a plugin that is re-enabling the context menu.