# Reactivate Browser context menu in ckeditor 4.5.x

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, otrs

I know I'm not the first with this question but none of all the answers found does work here. And there is no answer accepted by the community.
 Not sure if it's the version or simply my own stupidity.

We are using OTRS 5 with CKEditor 4.5.6 atm.

When my users are writing in this editor and want to use browser-based spellchecker they always have to click Ctrl (Strg) while right clicking. Otherwise there only appears a small CKEditor Context menu. "Cut, copy, paste"

Is there a way to reactivate the browser context menu with its spellchecker?

Answer (score 0):

> The plugin provides the editor's context menu to use instead of the browser's native
>    menu in place.
>
> It also provides the API to manage menu item and group.
>
> **With the presence of this plugin, the native context menu will still be available when Ctrl key is pressed** when opening the menu which can be configured as well.
>
> [Context Menu plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/contextmenu)

If it is a plugin, it can be turned off.

```
config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';
```

For further information see [config.removePlugins](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins) and [CKEDITOR.editorConfig](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-editorConfig).

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought and tried too. It don't work this way. 
It only replaces the CKEditor menu in the text field but not when i right click a wrong word.

Comment: ALso tried the suggestions from related threads but slightly lower versions.
None works.
e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183505/disable-ckeditor-context-menu-in-version-4-4-6?rq=1

This editor is awesome it would really hurt to replace it..